# ¿Se podría aplicar responsive design a este sitio web?

Tags: html, css, responsive

Ya tengo un sitio web hecho, estoy incursionando en esto del *responsive design* y me gustaría saber si esto podría darle el estilo de la imagen con el código que ya tengo o si tendría que modificar algo para que me quede lo más parecido a la imagen.

Adjunto el código y una imagen de cómo debería ser el *responsive design*.

```css
body {
  font-family: Montserrat,sans-serif;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*Barra de navegación*/
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.logo-img{
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.nav-bar {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex: auto;
  padding-right: 40px;
}
.nav-bar__link, .nav-bar__link-active {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
}
.nav-bar__link-active {
  color: black;
}

.nav-bar li{
  padding: 0 20px;

}

/*Foto principal*/
.principal-cover {
  background-image: url(../img/Viajes_Hero.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  color: white;
  height: 600px;
}

/* RECUADRO AMERICA DEL SUR */
.rectangle-info{
  margin-top: 200px;
}

.text-image {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.subtitle {
  font-size: 15px;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.subtitle-description {
  font-size: 12px;
}


/* RECUADRO PROXIMA AVENTURA */
.arrow-icon{
  padding-left:10px;
}
.logo-text {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);
  margin-top: 300px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px dashed #fff;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
  height: 120px;
  align-self: flex-end;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.text-red{
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #FA6980;
}

.text-white{
  font-family: Montserrat,Bold;
  font-size: 13px;
}


/*Seccion Tendencias*/

.container-tendencies{
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.title-tendencies{
  padding: 0 50px;
}

.tendencies-group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  
}
.tendencies-item {
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 355px;
  height: 200px;
  
}


/*Seccion Blog */
.container-blog{
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}


.all-blog-items{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px 5px;
}


/* IMAGENES GRANDES DE LA GRID */
.blog-item-big1{
  background-image: url(../img/articulo_big_01.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: white;
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / span 3 / span 2;
}


.blog-item-big2{
  background-image: url(../img/articulo_big_02.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: white;
  grid-area: 4 / 1 / span 3 / span 2;
  
}


/*IMAGENES PEQUEÑAS DE LA GRID*/
.blog-item-small1{
 grid-area: 1 / 3 / span 2 / span 1;

}

.blog-item-small2{
  grid-area: 3/ 3 / span 2 / span 1;

}

.blog-item-small3{
  grid-area: 5 / 3 / span 2 / span 1;
 
}

/*LETRAS DE LAS IMAGENES GRANDES DE LA GRID*/
.title-big-img1{
  margin: 30px 40px;
}

.subtitle-big-img1{
  margin-top:230px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.description-big-img1{
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.title-big-img2{
  margin: 30px 40px;
}

.subtitle-big-img2{
  margin-top:230px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.description-big-img2{
  margin-left: 40px;
}



.text-bold{
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* TEXTOS TIEMPO IMAGENES GRANDES*/
.text-tiny-grey-big{
  font-size: 12px;
  color:#CBD0D3;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

/* TEXTOS TIEMPO IMAGENES PEQUEÑAS*/
.text-tiny-grey-small{
  font-size: 12px;
  color:#CBD0D3;
}


/*FOOTER*/
.footer{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #2A3037;
}

.logo2{
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.icons-items{
  padding: 0 35px;
}


.hide-btn-menu{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Ejercicio Aenima</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="responsive.css"> 
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <header>
      <img class="logo-img" width="90px" class="logo" src="logo/logo_01.svg" alt="Logo">
      <label for="chk" class="hide-btn-menu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></label>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav-bar">
          <li>
            <a class="nav-bar__link-active" href="#">HOME</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="nav-bar__link" href="#">TENDENCIAS</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="nav-bar__link" href="#">BLOG</a>    
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container principal-cover">
      <div class="rectangle-info">
        <h1 class="text-image"><img class="icon-map" src="iconos/ic_pin.svg">AMÉRICA DEL SUR</h1>
        <h3 class="subtitle">Lugares maravillosos por America del Sur</h3>
        <p class="subtitle-description">Estos son algunos lugares que elijen la mayoría de los turistas que<br>visitan America del Sur</p>
      </div>
      <div class="logo-text">
        <p class="text-red">PRÓXIMA AVENTURA<img class="arrow-icon" src="iconos/arrow.svg" alt="logo"></p>
        <p class="text-white">Europa Meridional</p>
        <p class="text-description">Forman parte veinte países <br>ej.España,Francia,etc.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-tendencies">
      <h3 class="title-tendencies">TENDENCIAS</h3>
      <div class="tendencies-group">
        <div class="tendencies-item">
          <img class="image-text" src="img/card_01.png" alt="card1">
          <h3>Montañas y magia</h3>
          <p>Aquí la descripción para <b>Montañas y magia</b></p>
        </div>
        <div class="tendencies-item">
          <img src="img/card_02.png" alt="card2">
          <h3>Playa y sol</h3>
          <p>La descripción de <b> Playa y sol</b> debe ser esta</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tendencies-item">
          <img src="img/card_03.png" alt="card3">
          <h3>Nieve y aventura</h3>
          <p>Contiene la información de <b> Nieve y aventura</b></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-blog">
      <h3>BLOG</h3>
      <div class="all-blog-items">
        <div class="blog-item-big1"> 
          <h4 class="title-big-img1">CIUDAD</h4>
          <h3 class="subtitle-big-img1">Artículo de puente</h3>
          <p class="description-big-img1">Un puente es una construcción que permite salvar un accidente geógrafico</p>
          <p class="text-tiny-grey-big"><img src="iconos/time.svg" alt="time">Hace 2m</p>
        </div>
        <div class="blog-item-big2"> 
          <h4 class="title-big-img2">AVENTURA<h4>
          <h3 class="subtitle-big-img2">Artículo de Bosque</h3>
          <p class="description-big-img2">Lugar poblado de árboles y arbustos con una importante densidad de</p>
          <p class="text-tiny-grey-big"><img src="iconos/time.svg" alt="time">Hace 2m</p>
        </div>
        <div class="blog-item-small1">
          <img src="img/articulo_small_01.png" alt="item1">
          <p class="text-bold">Artículo de elefante</p>
          <p class="text-tiny-grey-small"><img src="iconos/time.svg" alt="time">Hace 3hs</p >
        </div>
        <div class="blog-item-small2">
          <img src="img/articulo_small_02.png" alt="item2">
          <p class="text-bold">Artículo de loro</p>
          <p class="text-tiny-grey-small"><img src="iconos/time.svg" alt="time">Hace 4hs</p>
        </div>
        <div class="blog-item-small3">
          <img src="img/articulo_small_03.png" alt="item3">
          <p class="text-bold">Artículo de camino</p>
          <p class="text-tiny-grey-small"><img src="iconos/time.svg" alt="time">Hace 8hs</p>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <img class="logo2" src="logo/logo_02.svg" alt="logo2">
        <div class="icons-items">
          <a href="#"><img src="iconos/instagram.svg"></a>
          <a href="#"><img src="iconos/facebook.svg"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer tu página responsive, lo que necesitas es "rediseñar" nuevamente tu página con el nuevo tamaño de pantalla, para evitar cambiar algo en el "nuevo diseño" usa los `media queries` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Siendo específicos, los `media queries` de tamaño:

```css
@media (min-width: ###px) { ... }
@media (max-width: ###px) { ... }
```

Por ejemplo, como tu diseño inicial es para monitores, el `css` en móviles para tu sección *tendencias* sería algo así (sólo pongo el código de dicha sección):

```css
body {
  font-family: Montserrat,sans-serif;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*Seccion Tendencias*/

.container-tendencies{
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.title-tendencies{
  padding: 0 50px;
}

.tendencies-group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.tendencies-item {
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 0 0 33.33%;
  max-width: 33.33%;
  height: 200px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .tendencies-item {
    flex: none;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Ejercicio Aenima</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="responsive.css"> 
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="container-tendencies">
      <h3 class="title-tendencies">TENDENCIAS</h3>
      <div class="tendencies-group">
        <div class="tendencies-item">
          <img class="image-text" src="img/card_01.png" alt="card1">
          <h3>Montañas y magia</h3>
          <p>Aquí la descripción para <b>Montañas y magia</b></p>
        </div>
        <div class="tendencies-item">
          <img src="img/card_02.png" alt="card2">
          <h3>Playa y sol</h3>
          <p>La descripción de <b> Playa y sol</b> debe ser esta</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tendencies-item">
          <img src="img/card_03.png" alt="card3">
          <h3>Nieve y aventura</h3>
          <p>Contiene la información de <b> Nieve y aventura</b></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Como puedes ver en el código, lo que está dentro del `media query` son modificadores CSS para cuando el navegador cumpla la condición indicada (en este ejemplo, si el navegador es máximo 800px de ancho).

Está perfecto que quieras tener las bases del diseño responsive, sólo dos consejos que te lo dirán en todo lado:

- Inicia primero con el diseño móvil, luego con un diseño mediano y finalmente el diseño para PC (usarás `min-width` en tus *media queries*).
- En cuanto estés familiarizado con el diseño responsive, aprende un framework CSS como Bootstrap (de los más populares) u otros, especialmente la sección de `grids`, así tus diseños serán más rápidos y efectivos.

Comment: La pregunta es un tanto amplia y como tal no debería ser respondida, de hecho ya lleva 2 votos de cierre

Comment: @Aprendiz lo siento, llevo poco más de una semana en la comunidad, dónde puedo ver si una publicación tiene *votos de cierre*?

Comment: Me parece que ese privilegio lo obtienes con 3000 de reputación

Comment: @Aprendiz gracias, de todas formas ya tengo el privilegio de reportarlo por ser pregunta extensa, saludos